# Forge viewer to load file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am able to load file in forge viewer. I have directly passing the current URN to loader function, its working without any token generation, conversion etc.(by simply passing urn only to loader function).

But the next day, I am passing same urn to loader function, the file is not loading.
Next day onwards not working.

we need to view the file always. How its possible. Please help me on this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you're loading a model via URN (which means it's coming from the Forge Model Derivative service), you *have to* provide some kind of a token. It's possible that on the first day your application *was* somehow using a hard-coded token but on the next day that same token was no longer valid.

See in this example how we're passing a `getAccessToken` function to `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer`: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/develop/public/main.js#L1. This function will be used by Forge Viewer whenever it needs a new or refreshed token to download the model from the Forge Model Derivative service.